# how to use TestMain with global aetest.NewInstance

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using
    "google.golang.org/appengine/aetest"
package and setup my TestMain like this:

```
var myAeInst aetest.Instance


func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    var err error
    myAeInst, err = aetest.NewInstance(&aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true})
    defer tearDown()

    c := m.Run()

    os.Exit(code)
}

func tearDown() {
    if myAeInst != nil {
        myAeInst.Close()
    }
}
```

But it stuck at aetest.NewInstance, any one encounter similar issue?

Comment: I found that this issue only exhibit when my go project is setup with multiple sub directory with different package name. If everything in the same folder and all test file using same package name, it works.
Has anyone tried to make TestMain works for multiple package case?
I need to be able to run the test using go test ./...

Comment: The only time I've seen anything similar to that was when the goapp was having trouble starting a new dev_appserver.py instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `defer tearDown()` and then `os.Exit(code)`, which calls `tearDown` *after* `os.Exit` (i.e., never). You need to either explicitly call `tearDown` before `os.Exit`, or make a new function that you defer from that *doesn't* call `os.Exit`.

Comment: This is the correct answer - os.Exit does not "respect" defer.